# User selected Google Earth overlays shown during Tour Player?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Can Google Earth web plugin support allowing a user to:
1. Use checkboxes to choose multiple map overlays to be displayed, and then
2. Click on a link to start a Tour Player tour, with all of the map overlays chosen in #1 being displayed inside the tour?

I can do #1, and I can do #2, but I can't figure out a way to have the choices from #1 be displayed within #2.

Here's a prototype website I've created for this project:
http://www.ppacg.org/google_earth/tours-4/

If this is possible, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. If this isn't possible, I would greatly appreciate hearing that so I can move on to a different approach.

Thanks!

paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by "displayed" you mean "visible", then everything should work as you expect.

I was unable to get any layers to load in your demo site, but for example if I load a KML (data.kml) that has some Placemarks or overlays, and then I load a KML with a Tour (tour.kml), and then I enter the tour and begin playing the tour, the content from data.kml will still be visible.

As an example of this you can modify the playground example of [playing a tour](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#playing_tours) by pasting in a portion of another example (such as loading good KML).  You'll note that the content does not disappear when the tour is loaded.

There are some caveats around whether you have time attributes on your content, but it seems unlikely this is the case here.

Comment: Thanks jlivni! I'm sorry I didn't respond sooner but I just now saw your comment.

Comment: Thanks again jlivni for your help! Here is the WIP solution I have come up with to have checkboxes for GE overlays alongside links for GE tours:

http://ppacg.org/tours/test-new.html

Here's one issue I still have, if anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it: My Internet Explorer 9 on Win 7 is having intermittent problem loading the GE plugin. This problem only seemed to appear after I added the code that runs the GE tours.

Also, if anyone has any general suggestions for improving my javascript, I would appreciate that too!

Comment: Update: I reinstalled the GE plugin and since then I haven't had any of the problems described in my previous comment.